# Screen execute "long term" command and get the log

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to get the log with long term commands from Screen, I tried several option, not works.

(I access to screen remote, via SSH /java.)

Here is the code:

```
screen -r new -X stuff "sudo apt-get update\n"
screen -x new -X hardcopy /home/user/new.log && cat new.log
```

The response of
`sudo apt-get purge nginx -y`

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgd3 libvpx3 nginx-common nginx-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nginx*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 84 not upgraded.
After this operation, 37.9 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 82697 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nginx (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
```

You can't get more log with that commands.
I would like to get the full log.

Commands executed successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to format code, select it with the mouse and click `{}` beside **Bold** and *Italic* in the formatting menu.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use day by day the Stackoverflow.. I thought markdown's code back-ticks is fine here too.

Comment: There's no need to apologise :-) I was just trying to help out and make life easier for you and others reading/editing your question. Markdown backticks do work but are best for the odd, occasional single word of code but a bit awkward for longer chunks of code.

Answer (score 0):

I do apologize, everything ok with that commands, just I remember bad.. what I need to get as *eg. nginx installation.